Two merged TIFF files show up as one flipped file, so in mirror-like outcome
I merged two TIFF files and the result is that the final merged TIFF file is in reverse mode, so in a kind of mirror-like outcome. I used both Qgis 3.38.3 and did the same exercise with 3.40.00

Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. All Questions should always state the exact GIS software in use, and provide details about the procedure. For imagery merge, you should provide the extents of the input sources, and the extent of the result. Please [Edit] the Question.

What software did you use?

I used both Qgis 3.38.3 and did the same exercise with 3.40.00
